# Extracting text - Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: excel, vba

I have written this VBA code and I get an error on line 12 (getName = Mid..) - Invalid procedure call or argument.  The aim of this is to find the first instance of a close bracket ")" then find the second instance of an open "(" bracket, and paste the text inbetween these 2 points into the next column. Can someone explain to my why I get this error?

```
Dim getName As String
    Dim part1 As Integer
    Dim part2 As Integer
    Dim part3 As Integer
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Set rRng = Sheet2.Range("B1:B10000")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Rows
    part1 = InStr(Path, ")")
    part2 = InStr(Path, "-")
    part3 = InStr(part2 + 1, Path, "(")
    getName = Mid(Path, part1 + 1, part3 - part1 - 1)
    Range("B1:B10000").Offset(RowOffSet:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Select.Value = getName
    Next rCell
    '
    End Sub
```

The data I am trying to parse:

```
TEST2_ (LC) HELLO (brtreq) - dgfdag - 43224 - Dec 08 to Dec 31 2014 - Ros - 2gd - Skin

TEST MOBILE STIE (LC) MOODY (FEREFE) - RDEWF- Jan 15 to Dec 31 2015 - Ros - HRWFEW (New) (2F4F4)

TEST GPTDFV SGE (LC) GRASS (HSK) - GSK - 23F23 - Jan 06 to Jan 31 2015 - Ros - WERWE - PSDF
```

Comment: Can you give example of some of the values you're trying to parse?  I see some errors in your code but would not expect that error.  For example as you are iterating the 10,000 cells, it was probably not your intention to write the value to ALL of them, every time. The end result of this will be that every one of these cells will contain ONLY the very last evaluation of the `getName` variable.

Comment: It's also not clear where, if anywhere, you have assigned any value to the `Path` variable.   That variable is not declared, and you do not assign it in the snippet provided. That could contribute to error(s).

Comment: I have edited my original question. So next to the column of these values I would like the values Hello, Moody and Grass.

Comment: Please see the other Q: what about the `path` variable?

Comment: Ah okay. So I need to assign the path variable to have the string value of the current selected cell in the loop?

Comment: Yes. without that, you're psasing a null string to the `Instr` function and you'll see if you debug it that values of all `part1` `part2` and `part3` variables are 0, which will cause that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, always use `Option Explicit`. This will prevent you from using undeclared variables, which was the source of your error here.

Without assigning to that variable, you're passing a null string or zero-value to the `Instr` function and you'll see if you debug it that values of all `part1` `part2` and `part3` variables are 0, which will cause that error.

You also have some bad logic in assigning to your `part` variables, which is passing a negative number to the `Mid` function, which will raise that error.

Try this. I have separated `GetPath` as its own function call:

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
Dim path As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = Sheet2.Range("A1:A3")

For Each rCell In rRng.Rows
    path = rCell.Value
    rCell.Offset(0,1).Value = GetName(path)
Next rCell

End Sub

Function GetName(path As String)

    Dim part1 As Integer
    Dim part2 As Integer
    Dim part3 As Integer
    Dim returnValue As String

    If Trim(path) = vbNullString Then GoTo EarlyExit 'handles empty strings

    part1 = InStr(path, ")")
    part2 = InStr(part1, path, ")") 'I changed this line
    part3 = InStr(part2 + 1, path, "(")

    returnValue = Trim(Mid(path, part1 + 1, part3 - part1 - 1))

EarlyExit:
    GetName = returnValue

End Function
```